# Convert dataframe column to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
   type       items
1  fruit      "apple, banana, orange"
2  vegetable  "tomato, carrot"
```

Note that each row in *items* is one value and **not** split by a delimiter. I need to convert each value in *items* to a single list, where each item is an independent value:

```
["apple", "banana", "orange", "tomato", "carrot"]
```

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `collapse = ", "` or the conveninent function `toString` to create a single string

```
toString(df1$items)
```

and if it needs to be a `vector` of values, wrap with `scan`

```
scan(text = toString(df1$items), what ="", sep =",",
        strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
```